# How can I cancel the click from window.onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a burguer menu and when I click outside the burguer menu it closes like I wanted, but it just continues the click and goes wherever I clicked to leave the burguer menu

```
window.onclick = function () {
        if ($scope.showMenuContent) {
            $scope.showMenuContent = false;
            $scope.$apply();
        }
};
```

I'm using angular js too, so the variable showMenuContent shows and hides my burguer menu.

I have already tried to stop propagation like this

```
window.onclick = function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if ($scope.showMenuContent) {
            $scope.showMenuContent = false;
            $scope.$apply();
        }
};
```

but it does not work!

Comment: Sounds like you should be using preventDefault() and it should only be called when the menu is open.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Its not a good practice to add and remove event listeners very often. What you can rather do is add a permanent event listener to the window and check whether the click was on the menu or not by using **event.toElement.id** and then take actions accordingly.

### Here is the source Code:

```js
let burger = document.getElementById('burger'),
  isOpen = false;


const closeMenu = e => {
  let _target = e.toElement.id;
  if(_target != 'burger' && isOpen) {
  //This will close if burger is open and you click elsewhere
    burger.classList.remove('open');
    isOpen = false;
  }
}

const toggleMenu = () => {
  if (!isOpen) {
  //opens the menu
    burger.classList.add('open');
    isOpen = true;
  } else {
  //closes the menu
    burger.classList.remove('open');
    isOpen = false;
  }
}

window.addEventListener('click', closeMenu, false);
```

```css
#burger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.open {
  width: 300px !important;
  height: 300px !important;
  background: black !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="burger" onclick="toggleMenu()"></div>
```

Comment: It actually didnt work for me problably because I cant use the latest version of JS. But I solved it by creating a div behind my burguer menu with a different z-index which made it work and block outside clicks. But thank you by the way, appreciate it